# Kafka consumer fetching metadata for topics failed

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am attempting to write a Java client for a third party's Kafka and ZooKeeper servers. I am able to list and describe topics, but when I attempt to read any, a `ClosedChannelException` is raised. I reproduce them here with the command line client.

```
$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper 255.255.255.255:2181 --topic eventbustopic
[2015-06-02 16:23:04,375] WARN Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 0 for topics [Set(eventbustopic)] from broker [id:1,host:SOME_HOST,port:9092] failed (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException                                       
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)           
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)        
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)                
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)        
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:93)        
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:66)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:60)         
[2015-06-02 16:23:04,515] WARN Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 0 for topics [Set(eventbustopic)] from broker [id:0,host:SOME_HOST,port:9092] failed (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException                                       
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)           
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)        
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)                
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)        
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:93)        
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:66)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:60)
```

Alternate commands succeed:

```
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper 255.255.255.255:2181 --topic eventbustopic
Topic:eventbustopic   PartitionCount:2        ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:
    Topic: eventbustopic  Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
    Topic: eventbustopic  Partition: 1    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0

$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper 255.255.255.255:2181 --topic eventbustopic
eventbustopic
```

(The ips were redacted and replaced with 255.255.255.255)

When I google this exception, I see issues on the producer side -- indeed, the source for `ClientUtils.fetchTopicMetadata` suggests this is mainly used by producers.

One concern that I have is that this might be a product of the network layout: the packets are mangled by Haproxy and sent over a VPN.

What exactly is at work here?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The broker tells the client which hostname should be used to produce/consume messages. By default Kafka uses the hostname of the system it runs on. If this hostname can not be resolved by the client side you get this exception.

You can try setting `advertised.host.name` in the Kafka configuration to an hostname/address which the clients should use.

Comment: Seem like all middleware programmed with java have to set /etc/hosts to run normal. You have to config Producer and Consumer ip in to hosts file. Thank you Johannes.

Comment: Just for anyone else running into this, it could also be that the JVM has an -Xmx or resource constraints (Docker) are too low. You get the exact same error.

Comment: @DonovanMuller your comment should probably be posted as a full answer to this question. It was the one answer that solved my problem and I suspect that it may well help others the same way, but as a comment it is easy to miss

Answer (score 12):

Here is my way to solve this problem:

1. run `bin/kafka-server-stop.sh` to stop running kafka server.
2. modify the properties file `config/server.properties` by adding a line:
   `listeners=PLAINTEXT://{ip.of.your.kafka.server}:9092`
3. restart kafka server.

Since without the lisener setting, kafka will use `java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName()` to get the address which the socket server listens on.

Comment: If used the old version like 0.8.1.x, the same property named `host.name` and `advertised.port`

Comment: Came across same problem and the listeners=PLAINTEXT://{ip.of.your.kafka.server}:9092 helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with Zookeeper. `255.255.255.255:2181` is not a valid Zookeeper address; this is a broadcast address on your network or a subnet mask. To make the things work, find the IP Address or hostname of the machine running Zookeeper.

Comment: The ips were redacted and replaced with 255.255.255.255. I could've been clearer about that.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this error on AWS. Problem was I was overly restrictive with the security group and set ports 2181 and 9092 to "my IP". This meant the kafka instance couldn't find the ZK running on the same box.

Solution - open it up - a little.