# GetKafka not getting messages in Apache Nifi

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

I'm trying to get the messages using a GetKafka processor but I'm not able to get it. I tested consuming messages using Kafka command line consumer and it works. I was also able to use PutKafka processor successfully to put the messages in the topic. Attached my settings where I set the Zookeeper Connection String and Topic Name. When I run the flow, I don't see any errors in the processors.

[GetKafka Processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSkgB.jpg)

I see an exception in nifi-app.log:

```
2016-08-03 09:34:33,722 WARN [70e1df87-6097-4ed0-9a40-7e36f9be6921_mydomain.com-1470231250839-1fbd0cfe-leader-finder-thread] kafka.client.ClientUtils$ Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 0 for topics [Set(test)] from broker [id:0,host:DataSlave1.CSE-RD.com,
port:9092] failed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException: null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202) ~[na:1.8.0_101]                                                                                                                                                          
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.poll(SocketChannelImpl.java:957) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
```

Kafka (0.8): 2.10-0.8.2.1, Nifi: 0.7.0
Am I missing anything? Thanks.

Comment: What versions of Kafka and NiFi are you using?

Comment: Kafka (0.8): 2.10-0.8.2.1, Nifi: 0.7.0

Comment: Ok is DataSlave1.CSE-RD.com a resolvable hostname from where NiF is running?

Comment: Yes - it's a resolvable name.

Comment: Ok if it is resolvable then I am not sure... It seems like most people are getting this error when the Kafka broker tells the client what the hostname is, and then the client can't connect to it. This post has the same error and most people had to set the advertised hostname of the broker: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606447/kafka-consumer-fetching-metadata-for-topics-failed

Comment: Thanks Bryan Bende!

Answer (score 0):

The exception went away after a restart. GetKafka is now able to get the messages as they are sent in the producer. It was not receiving the previous messages in the topic (something equivalent to --from-beginning in kafka console consumer). I don't see a setting for that in the processor.